# RTSP vs HLS vs WebRTC vs Dash (proper use cases)

Tags: video-streaming, audio-streaming

Modern era has been of video streaming—be it live stream or of recorded videos.

While studying I do come across the diverse protocols that are mentioned in subject of question. The more  protocols makes the use cases further intriguing; having said that I couldn't locate proper comparative evaluation and use cases.

Can someone help about use cases and critical differences, so that can understand when to use which one?

Also, any unified protocol that can display stream in browser, desktop application, and mobile App (Android and iOS)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-better-for-live-streaming-RTMP-vs-HLS-vs-WebRTC#:~:text=WebRTC%20is%20more%20focused%20for%20one%2Dto%2Done%20streaming.&text=Streaming%2C%20or%20HLS.-,Originally%20developed%20by%20Apple%20to%20enable%20them%20to%20drop%20Flash,Android%20and%20iOS%20mobile%20devices.) found with google search

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WebRTC: Can broadcast from browser, Low latency. More complicated server side, More expensive to operate due to lack of CDN support. Difficult to scale.

RTSP: Low latency, Will not work in any browser (broadcast or receive). No CDN support.

HLS: Works almost everywhere. Works over HTTP. Cheeper bandwidth due to CDN support. a lot of off the shelf easy to use and cheep/free server software available. Higher latency than other options.

Dash: pretty much the same as HLS, but has limited iOS support.