# Does Netflix use WebRTC for video streaming

Tags: video-streaming, netflix

I want to build a website that have video streaming like netflix as my sideproject. I would like to know whether they build their own way the solution for video streaming or they use also webrtc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netflix primarily uses DASH ([Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP)), but also has some other fallback encoding profiles (depending on platform). As far as I can tell, WebRTC is not used by Netflix.

[Wikipedia has some more technical background on Netflix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_details_of_Netflix), while a [different thread here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62682891/rtsp-vs-hls-vs-webrtc-vs-dash-proper-use-cases) sheds some light on advantages and disadvantages of several streaming options.